# Is there way to export overleaf document in to a .doc or .docx file?

Tags: overleaf, conversion, msword

I'm trying to convert an overleaf project to a .doc or .docx file. Does anybody know if this even possible?

Comment: Yes, see https://www.kodymirus.cz/overleaf-html-sample/main.html. you need to pass 'make4ht -f odt -d out main.tex'.

Comment: I'm new, so can't upvote yet, but llz1722 is correct! "You can use Microsoft word to open the pdf downloaded from overleaf. The pdf will be automatically converted to a normal word document (enable you to comment and everything)."

Answer (score 16):

You can use Microsoft word to open the pdf downloaded from overleaf.

The pdf will be automatically converted to a normal word document (enable you to comment and everything).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is indeed a [feature of (newer versions of?) MS Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/opening-pdfs-in-word-1d1d2acc-afa0-46ef-891d-b76bcd83d9c8). But in contrast to the other cited software like `make4ht` or `pandoc`, which are open source, you cannot see how it exactly is working and, as far as I could find, it is documented far less detailed. For a quick conversion, however, this may still be sufficient.

Answer (score 14):

You can try using pandoc: https://pandoc.org/

Use the following command:

```
pandoc -o output.docx -t docx  input.tex
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: not useful, getting errors in \bm and also figures aren't included in docx.

Answer (score 5):

I have actually had a lot of issues with `pandoc` when trying to convert a scientific paper, especially concerning resized/split images and missing references.

However I had very acceptable results that only needed minor polishing when using a free web conversion service (https://smallpdf.com/pdf-to-word) to convert the `.pdf` that I generated from Overleaf to a `.docx` file.

Comment: smallpfd.com website is not accessible

Comment: For me, the link works.